# Azure Pipeline Node.js run localhost server(express) and client at different port to run jest tests

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am running a client application(JS) using Node.js on port 8080. At same time, I am running an Express Server using Node.js at port 3030.

Integration tests are written in Jest and Selenium. To test app, on my local machine, I open three Powershell windows and run Integration tests. It works as expected and test case passes.

```
Server Folder (new Terminal)
 npm install
 npm run start (Express.js)

Client Folder (new Terminal)
 npm install
 npm run start

Client Folder (new Terminal)
 npm run tests
```

In Azure Pipeline, I created YML for image 'window-latest', However it stuck at Server Start.

```
powershell:
display name: Server Start
  npm install
  npm run start

powershell:
display name: Client Start
  npm install
  npm run start | npm run test (Combined in package.json)
```

If I remove `Server Start` in Azure Pipeline, test cases that do not need server pass.

Both projects are under one repository. I use cd command in Package.json to install and start server at server location.

```
start:server: "cd /server/dev/ && npm install && npm run start"
start:client: "npm install && npm run start"
test: "npm run start:server | npm run start:client | jest"
```

npm run test, works fine on my local machine, server & client runs and test cases pass(single terminal). On Azure Pipeline, I need to Cancel task manually because the Azure pipeline task never ends. After separating scripts(Powershell), I noticed pipeline stuck on Express.js Server Start(Tested by running single and combined npm commands in YAML).

Question: How can I start localhost Express Node.js server in Azure Pipeline before starting Client?

Answer (score 0):

You may check [start-server-and-test](https://www.npmjs.com/package/start-server-and-test):

> Starts server, waits for URL, then runs test command; when the tests
> end, shuts down server.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not allow binding to a port on Hosted Agents.
You must own a self hosted agent to do that.

Comment: Do you have a source for this ?

Comment: As of mid October 2021, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted does not mention this limitation.
So it might well be possible now?